# Linux pppd ipv6 failure: not cannot determine local address

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ipv6, point-to-point-protocol

I am trying to use pppd to establish ipv6 connection over a 4g modem.  ipv4 has succeeded but ipv6 have not.

The pppd is 2.4.7.

pppd config:

```
+ipv6
ipv6cp-accept-local
```

Note: the pppd does not accept 'ipv6cp-accept-remote' option.

chat script:

```
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IPV6","myapn"
```

pppd logs:

```
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 07 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::6c75:85ea:54cb:25e6>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 07 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::6c75:85ea:54cb:25e6>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 07 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfRej id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::6c75:85ea:54cb:25e6>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfNak id=0x1 <addr fe80::14a7:1bbd:e479:c9eb>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addrs 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0> <compress VJ 07 01>]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfNak id=0x1 <addr fe80::14a7:1bbd:e479:c9eb>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr fe80::f08a:2c87:c7dc:aa6e>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addrs 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0> <compress VJ 07 01>]
sent [IPCP ConfRej id=0x2 <addrs 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr fe80::f08a:2c87:c7dc:aa6e>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfNak id=0x2 <addr fe80::0136:b136:6e32:344d>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x2 <addrs 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <compress VJ 07 01>]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfNak id=0x2 <addr fe80::0136:b136:6e32:344d>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr fe80::4042:1547:076f:1770>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <compress VJ 07 01>]
sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x3 <compress VJ 07 01>]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr fe80::4042:1547:076f:1770>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfNak id=0x3 <addr fe80::7599:2d43:33e1:9216>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x3 <compress VJ 07 01>]
Could not determine local IP address
Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Sent 230 bytes, received 188 bytes.
sent [IPCP TermReq id=0x4 "Could not determine local IP address"]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfNak id=0x3 <addr fe80::7599:2d43:33e1:9216>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x4 <addr fe80::e0aa:2a9c:4117:e47f>]
rcvd [IPCP TermReq id=0x4 "Could not determine local IP address"]
sent [IPCP TermAck id=0x4]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x4 <addr fe80::e0aa:2a9c:4117:e47f>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfNak id=0x4 <addr fe80::64ca:b418:01f0:97dc>]
rcvd [IPCP TermAck id=0x4]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfNak id=0x4 <addr fe80::64ca:b418:01f0:97dc>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x5 <addr fe80::2dc9:d268:a2da:a5ed>]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x5 <addr fe80::2dc9:d268:a2da:a5ed>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfNak id=0x5 <addr fe80::54ab:e16f:42bb:17d3>]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfNak id=0x5 <addr fe80::54ab:e16f:42bb:17d3>]
sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x6]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x6]
sent [IPV6CP ConfAck id=0x6]
rcvd [IPV6CP ConfAck id=0x6]
Could not determine remote LL address
cif6addr: ioctl(SIOCDIFADDR): No such address
sent [IPV6CP TermReq id=0x7 "Could not determine remote LL address"]
rcvd [IPV6CP TermReq id=0x7 "Could not determine remote LL address"]
sent [IPV6CP TermAck id=0x7]
rcvd [IPV6CP TermAck id=0x7]
sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "No network protocols running"]
rcvd [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "No network protocols running"]
sent [LCP TermAck id=0x2]
rcvd [LCP TermAck id=0x2]
Connection terminated.
```

Do you think it looks like my pppd problem or my provider problem?  Thank in advance!

Comment: Your end is rejecting the IPv6 address received from the other end, and the other end is rejecting the IPv6 address your end proposes. Curiously, it's also failing to get an IPv4 address. How to fix this, I have no idea. Do you have to use PPP at all?

Comment: Yes, I have to PPP.  If I select IPv6 using "AT+CGDCONT=1,"IPV6","myapn", it will success.